# Python to query from MS SQL and load into PostgreSQL efficiently

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

What is the most efficient way to transfer a fairly large amount of data (2mil+ rows) every day from MS SQL to PostgreSQL?

Right now I:

- Connect to the database with SQLAlchemy
- Read the data with pandas (WHERE report_date = yesterday)
- I was then adding some columns and stuff in pandas but I **do not** need to do this anymore. I can simply grab the data and load it directly without making modifications
- Then I write the dataframe to a CSV file and use psycopg2 to bulk insert it

Code sample:

for query_date in date_range:
    query= 'SELECT * FROM {} WHERE row_date = %s;'
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query.format(table_name), engine, params={query_date})

```
def process_file(conn, table_name, file_object):
   fake_conn = pg_engine.raw_connection()
   fake_cur = fake_conn.cursor()
   fake_cur.copy_expert(sql='''COPY %s FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER''' % table_name, file=file_object)
   fake_conn.commit()
   fake_cur.close()


df.to_csv('../raw/temp_' + table_name + ext, index=False)
df = open('../raw/temp_' + table_name + ext)
process_file(conn=pg_engine, table_name=table_name, file_object=df)
```

Comment: Have you tried using [linked servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)?

Comment: Not familiar, sorry. I should add that I only have read-only access to the MS SQL source database. I can query from it, but I am unable to do anything else (even add indexes or rename things). So my solution should be, ideally, something that queries for data daily for the previous day from the MS SQL source and then writes that data to our local PostgreSQL database.

Comment: You can also try the reverse direction, using [foreign data wrappers](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers). These are theoretically more efficient because they don't need an intermediary to funnel the data. If you can't do this either, the next best thing would be to stream the data in both directions.